# Installing third party Objective-C library within Swift 3 / Xcode 8 (SharkORM)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, swift3

Im pretty new to Xcode/Swift and want to install a third party library(SharkORM).

I drag'n'dropped the folder "SharkORM" into XCode and selected "Create groups". Then i created a file "Swift-Bridging-Header.h" and typed in `#include “SharkORM.h”` as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/sharksync/sharkorm). When i hold CMD and click on it it leads me to the interface declaration(good!?). Now when i try to use it: `class MyClass: SRKObject { ... }` i get an error: "Use of undeclared type 'SRKObject'". But i can CMD+click on it which leads me to the interface declaration again.

I tried to install with Cocoapod, too, with no success.

Comment: If you install with CocoaPods all you have to do is `import SharkORM` at the top of your Swift class

Comment: What issue you are getting when using it with cocoa pods ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted on GitHub, it sounds like the header file you created has not been added to the build settings as the chosen bridging header.

That is the most likely scenario leading to the object not being defined in your swift code.

Comment: Yes thank you! Under build settings there is an option "Objective-C Bridging Header". I added "projectgroup/Swift-Bridging-Header.h" there. Also i needed to clean (Product -> Clean).

Comment: Excellent, glad you got it working.  As soon as my rep goes above 1k i'll create a sharkorm tag and then get notified of any problems a lot faster in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Check, if SharkORM.h contains SRKObject declaration. If not, find header file with it and place it to bridging header too